# Could we know if an address contains a specific token via Etherscan API?

Tags: tokens, wallets, etherscan

I tried this, http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&address=0x2c1ba59d6f58433fb1eaee7d20b26ed83bda51a3&startblock=0&endblock=2702578&sort=asc&apikey=KEYHERE

but it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use the Etherscan API? You could do this pretty easily with the web3/JSONRPC API built into Ethereum nodes themselves.

Comment: Assuming someone doesn't want to get down to the hassle of learning how to use web3js or running own Ethereum node but still somehow wants to know if a particular address owns a token. I guess that is what API is for - a neutral programming interface (NPI).